# Rendering Array of Images in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, image, object, render

I need help. I have been searching similar posts, but none of them solved my problem (imagesPool.js)

```js
import React from 'react';
const imagesPool = [
  { src: './images/starbucks.png'},
  { src: './images/apple.png'},
  { src: './images/mac.png'}
];

export default imagesPool;
```

Rendering the images (App.js) :

```js
import React from "react";
import imagesPool from './imagesPool';

const App = () => {
   return (
     <div>
       <img src={imagesPool} />
     </div>
)};

export default App;
```

Result : No images being displayed

Comment: `imagesPool` is an array. Also, I think you don't need to import React if you're just exporting an array?

Comment: You need some lib to make it, by now it only shows the array content: the path string

Comment: yes @JosephD. , any idea how to display the array of images . I don't want to use class.

Comment: @JosephD. Any simple ways to just render it to <img /> ?

Comment: @NanoMan please see answers below. The point for the duplicate is to use `.map()` to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should loop through your images because `src` expects a string location to the image.

```
import imagesPool from './imagesPool';

const App = () => {

  return (
     <div>
       {imagesPool.map((imgSrc, index) => (<img src={imgSrc.src} key={index} alt="Make sure to include a alt tag, because react might throw an error at build"/>))}
    </div>
)};
```

Comment: It doesn't work either.

Comment: That was a typo. Try now.

Comment: It shows 3 images icon, the real images don't show.

Comment: This means your image src is not valid. @JosephD. is right. Put your images folder in public

Comment: Earlier @JosephD. said that I needed to put my images folder in public, this solved my problem. But his comment disappeared, I can't find his comment. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

You always need to import React from 'react' if you are rendering jsx/tsx. In your code, you are returning jsx, thus you need to import react.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import imagesPool from './imagesPool';

    const App = () => {
        return (
           <div>
               {imagesPool.map((image) => <img key={image.src} src={image.src} />)}  
           </div>
         )};
  export default App;
```

Comment: thx, missed a closing bracket

Answer (score 1):

In react you solve things like conditionals, iterating, etc. with javascript (Remember, `<img>` is also just javascript and gets parsed into `React.createElement("img")`).

Since `img` expects a string in the `src`-property, we need to iterate over the array of sources and produce an `img`-Element for every source:

```
<div>
{
  imagesPool.map(({ src }) => (<img key={src} src={src} />))
}
</div>
```

With `key` you tell react how to recognize that an element is the same with subsequent renderings.

Comment: I tried it, it shows 3 images icon, but the real images don't show.

Comment: consider that your src paths don't work - this has then nothing to do with react